# Adding a space with xsl between xml elements of the same name, some nested

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" >
<us-claim-statement>What is claimed is:</us-claim-statement>
<claims id="claims">
<claim id="CLM-00001" num="00001">
<claim-text>1. A computer-implemented method, comprising:
<claim-text>receiving data comprising:
<claim-text>image data depicting in the user device; and</claim-text>
<claim-text>motion data in the user device;</claim-text>
</claim-text>
<claim-text>determining of the user;</claim-text>
<claim-text>determining motion data;</claim-text>
<claim-text>processing the user; and</claim-text>
<claim-text>based on the user.</claim-text>
</claim-text>
</claim>
<claim id="CLM-00002" num="00002">
<claim-text>2. The method of <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref>, wherein the comprises:
<claim-text>identifying in the image data;</claim-text>
<claim-text>retrieving  object;</claim-text>
<claim-text>based on the reference object; and</claim-text>
<claim-text>determining  the proportion.</claim-text>
</claim-text>
</claim>
</claims>
</us-patent-grant>
```

and this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <reed-patents>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </reed-patents>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="us-patent-grant | us-patent-application">
    <xsl:element name="patent-info">


        <xsl:element name="claim1TextAttempt1">         
            <xsl:for-each select="claims/claim[@id='CLM-00001']/claim-text">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="claim1TextAttempt2">         
            <xsl:for-each select="claims/claim[@id='CLM-00001']">
                <xsl:value-of select="claim-text" />
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>   
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get a result like this:

```
<claim1Text>1. A computer-implemented method, comprising:
receiving data comprising:
image data depicting in the user device; andmotion data in the user device;determining of the user;determining motion data;processing the user; andbased on the user.</claim1Text>
```

For both attempts....

With "andmotion" and "andbased" concatenated, not as separate words. I'd like these to be separate. I can remove:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

but then it looks messy. Is there something different I can do in the xsl to add spaces? I'm using xsl 1.0. Thank you very much!

edit - 
Expected Result (a space in 'and based' and 'and motion'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reed-patents>
   <patent-info>
      <claim1Text>1. A computer-implemented method, comprising:
receiving data comprising:
image data depicting in the user device; and motion data in the user device;determining of the user;determining motion data;processing the user; and based on the user.</claim1Text>

   </patent-info>
</reed-patents>
```

Comment: Could you post the expected result of transforming the given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <reed-patents>
        <patent-info>
            <xsl:for-each select="claims/claim">
                <claimText>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </claimText>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </patent-info>
    </reed-patents>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="claim-text/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="last-char" select="substring(., string-length())" />
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($last-char)">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reed-patents>
   <patent-info>
      <claimText>1. A computer-implemented method, comprising:
receiving data comprising:
image data depicting in the user device; and motion data in the user device; determining of the user; determining motion data; processing the user; and based on the user. </claimText>
      <claimText>2. The method of claim 1, wherein the comprises:
identifying in the image data; retrieving object; based on the reference object; and determining the proportion. </claimText>
   </patent-info>
</reed-patents>
```

---

### Added:

To get the text only from the first claim, make the first template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <reed-patents>
        <patent-info>
            <claimText>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="claims/claim[@id='CLM-00001']" />
            </claimText>
        </patent-info>
    </reed-patents>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: For this post, I'm only looking at "claim id=CLM-00001". I posted two attempts... I'll try simplifying my expected result to show only one result.

Comment: @Oleg What difference does it make?

Comment: I'm trying to get the readable text from everything in only "CLM-00001"

Comment: Is it possible to do it with the structure of the xsl file I'm using? The way the templates are laid out is different (and probably incorrectly) with lots of <xsl:for-each...

Comment: "*I'm trying to get the readable text from everything in only "CLM-00001"*" it's a trivial adjustment - see the addition to my answer. --"*Is it possible to do it with the structure of the xsl file I'm using?*" I don't think so. It is difficult enough as it is, and even my approach is not perfect (there is an extra space at the end).

Comment: Alright, thank you, I really appreciate it! ... but now I have lots of work to do to rewrite the xsl file, though it's for the best I imagine.

Comment: I am not sure you *have* to do that (although as you say, it would be beneficial for other reasons). But you *could* just change the part where you call `<xsl:for-each select="claims/claim[@id='CLM-00001']/claim-text">` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="claims/claim[@id='CLM-00001']" />` and add the extra template.